# Declaration or statement expected error when setting up Typescript 1.4 and angularjs2 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I have been trying to get a basic Typescript + Angular2 application going in VisualStudio 2013 . I have installed npm and tsd and having no luck following this tutorial 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio

At then I get this error

[image: Import statement not recognized]

[image: My Typescript folder]

[image: Project settings]

I can't figure out why visual studio won't recognize the import statement. Typescript itself seems to work but the import statement doesn't.

Any help greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Import is not supported in TypeScript 1.4.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan . It was really as simple as that. The article didn't mention this - things like this can totally send a beginner off track